# How to manipulate xml file's variable in Karate DSL?

Tags: testing, soap, cucumber, bdd, karate

There are very limited numbered examples for SOAP services with Karate DSL.

What am I trying to do is, creating an XML file which I am going to use it later as template. Since it is going to be a template, I need to make some parts of it dynamic.
It is easy to make it on **.json** files, but I couldn't find an example to make it happen for **.xml** files.

Let's sasy below one is my **.xml** file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.bigldap.ttech.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ws:createwMsisdn>
        <name></name>
        <password>1</password>
        <appId>1</appId>
    </ws:createwMsisdn>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I want to convert **name** part to dynamic variable.

I've tried **.replace** and **.set** methods of Karate, but it didn't work.

```
* def user = read ('classpath:xxx/assign-name-password.xml')
* replace user.name = anotheruser.username
* print user
```

When print works, it shows only  tags to me, as empty tags. ()
I couldn't find any related example.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have missed this set of examples, it is referred to in the documentation but not part of the demos: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/b329d50e0042e76b20544138bf3fb31a79892f90/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)

I think you will like what you find. There are plenty of options including via data-driven tables, here below are just a couple:

```
* def name = 'John Smith'
* def xml =
"""
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.bigldap.ttech.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ws:createwMsisdn>
        <name>#(name)</name>
        <password>1</password>
        <appId>1</appId>
    </ws:createwMsisdn>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""
* match xml//name == 'John Smith'
* set xml/Envelope/Body/createwMsisdn/name = 'Jane Doe'
* match xml//name == 'Jane Doe'
```

Comment: I saw these, but they don't work properly I guess. I've tried all of them but ithey didn't work. I am printing my xml, and I am seeing that my name variable still seen as #(name).

Comment: @Prometheus wow, ok. it is time to point you to this, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks, but not needed. Sorry for the extra time to get the problem. It is working! I've been trying this since you've written, but apparently my code lines were mislocated. I have more lines of tests and wanted to paste here only needed part. When I changed some of the lines, it worked. What am I trying to say is your solution works!

Comment: Can you share this solution?